# Angular ng-model with required

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, validation, required

I'm trying to create a simple input with html5 "required". I'm using placeholder, so I'd like the initial value of the input to be empty. I have the input bound to a ng-model that is initialized as empty (so the placeholder shows).
When I go to the page, it shows that input is required for the , which shouldn't show unless the user submits the form and the input is empty. 
how can I do this:

```
<input type="text" required ng-model="name">
..in controller:
$scope.name = "";
```

and not have the form think I am submitting an empty input?

Comment: can you rephrase this: 'When I go to the page, it shows that input is required for the , '? I'm having difficulty understanding the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of only validating when the user has actually interacted with your input element is to use $dirty to determine wether to show your error message. e.g.

```
<span ng-show="form.name.$dirty && form.name.$error.required">
      Name is required
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is actually a really nice little solution. I was hoping to use the automatic required message that the browser gives you, but this will work quite well too.

Answer (score 0):

I just created an example of form validation regarding to your question

```
This should be working:
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/6PTNg3atPHAjL0XFtvWj?p=preview